# Adding lines to file

Tags: sed, awk

I need help regarding adding some lines to a file; for expamle, I grep from text this parameters and save it to File1:

```
cellIdentity="461"
cellIdentity="465"
cellIdentity="462"
cellIdentity="466"
cellIdentity="463"
cellIdentity="467"
```

And now I need to create another file, File2 that looks like:

```
cellIdentity="461"
cellIdentity="465"
 cellIdentity="468"
cellIdentity="462"
cellIdentity="466"
 cellIdentity="469"
cellIdentity="463"
cellIdentity="467"
 cellIdentity="460"
```

Three new lines I spaced out.
So basically, I need to add these 3 lines, the last digit's 8,9,0 are always the same in these three lines, and the first two digit's are like in other lines.
I don't know if it is possible to do it. I was trying with the sed command but no luck.
I'm using /bin/csh in solaris. Any help/tips would be great.

Thanks

Comment: where does the text for the new lines come from? (i.e. a file?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("8 9 0",a," ")}NR%2==0{t=$0;sub(/.$/,a[++i],$2);$0=t RS $0}1' FS=\" OFS=\" file

cellIdentity="461"
cellIdentity="465"
cellIdentity="468"
cellIdentity="462"
cellIdentity="466"
cellIdentity="469"
cellIdentity="463"
cellIdentity="467"
cellIdentity="460"
```

#### Explanation

- `FS=\" OFS=\"` define field separator `"`
- `BEGIN{split("8 9 0",a," ")}` define the 8,9,0 in array `a` in BEGIN part
- `NR%2==0` find the odd lines
- `sub(/.$/,a[++i],$2)` replace the last character in column 2 which get from array `a` one after one
- `1`  same as print

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1{x;s/^/890/;x};2~2{p;G;s/(.)("\n)(.)(.*)/\3\2\4\3/;P;s/.*\n//;h;d}' file
```